# mysql have internal (special) word "to"?

Tags: mysql

I have column "to" in table, when I write query

```
SELECT to FROM mytable
```

mysql_error returns error, if insert word **to** into `` quotes, that is

```
SELECT `to` FROM mytable
```

query works, I search but not found, so tell please, what means "to" in mysql ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, used in [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) queries to assign permissions 'to' a user

Answer (score 1):

`TO` is a [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySql so the backticks are required to query:

```
SELECT `to` 
FROM mytable
```

Here is a [List of current Reserved Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588072/mysql-have-internal-special-word-to) in MySQL. Any items on the list need to be surrounded with the backticks `` ` ``.